# event job scheduling using quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

how we can do  scheduling for an event like ink is below some specified quantity.please give some code piece

Comment: Did you even try? Anything? I bet the quartz documentation provides a rather simple example like that...

Answer (score 3):

[Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is for time-based scheduling of jobs. It cannot, by itself, react to arbitrary events, like the ink in your printer being below a certain level.

The Quartz website contains extensive [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/index.html) on how to schedule jobs.